# PIP permission denied on Mac OSX even with --user

Tags: python, macos, pip

I've recently come to know the terrors of using pip with sudo to install packages. Instead, it is recommended using the --user flag. The problem is that even with the user flag I can't install ANYTHING with PIP, accusing of permission denied. Anyone ever had this problem before?

Here's a little demo of the error when trying to install the package Cython:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/myusername/Library/Python/2.7'
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

P.S: I know about the alternative of using a virtualenv, but I really wanna stick to using pip on the clear.

Edit: It turns out I have access to /Library/Python but not to ~/Library/Python. Which seems strange to me, why would I have access to systemwide files but not to my own? Is this normal?

Comment: You should use a virtualenv. Why wouldn't you? At any rate you should be able to install packages globally by using `sudo`

Comment: I want to avoid using sudo because of security issues. Not really nice running arbitrary python code from the web with sudo permissions.

Comment: Did you `chown -R username:staff /Library/Python` by accident?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't remember doing that. But the question still remains, shouldn't I have access to ~/Library/Python? I don't know if it's SIP's doing or just something terrible wrong with my system.

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -l /Users/myusername/` and `ls -l /Users/myusername/Library/`. It seems like either the root user owns it or another user.

Comment: I have ownership of everything, except for /Users/myusername/Library/Python, which is owned by root. Is this usual?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sudo command.

```
 sudo pip install cython
```